# PHP HTML \t and Tab Troubles

Tags: php, html, regex, tabs, syntax-highlighting

I have started making a syntax highlighter in php (only a quick one) and so far I have got a code box generator (aka it creates a table with styles that looks good and can display source code and html code). At the moment when writing code with it I do this:

```
$code = "def example_ruby_code(does_it_work)
" .     "(insert tab here) @does_it_work = false
" .     "end"
codebox($code, "title_here.rb")
```

My trouble is that I know that I can't have tabs in html so I used the following:

```
preg_replace("/\t/", "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp ", $code)
```

(this went in the codebox function)
But it doesn't seem to work, the output just shows no indentation whatsoever. Any ideas? Thanks in advance, ell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the semi-colon thing but I'v realised I'v been a complete moron, instead of setting the new value I just called preg_replace! Silly me! Thanks anyway, it still wouldn't of worked without the semi colons. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You are missing semi-colon after `&nbsp`:

```
preg_replace("/\t/", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", $code);
```

**Note:** You may find [`highlight_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php) function useful.